# tried to yank the door open

Tags: word-choice, word-request

The man ran down the aisle, got to the emergency exit door and tried to yank it open.

1. Is "yank" natural here?
2. Is "yank" interchangeable with "pull"?
3. The man really wants to get off. Which one of "yank" and "pull" sounds more forceful and desperate?

Answer (score 1):

'Yank' sounds more a little more forceful because it has a nuance of a sudden burst of energy. 'Pull' is a more general term but has the sense of a more sustained action. They are similar, of course, but 'yank' is generally a more quick and powerful movement than 'pull'.